# OpenGL perspective projection to map the screen pixels

Tags: c++, opengl, projection, perspective

I am trying to set up perspective projection in OpenGL such that it maps exactly to the screen pixels, like we can do in orthographic projections. I can do this for specific screen sizes, for example 640x960, but cannot do it for any screen size. Below is the code I have used to set it up for 640x960 size

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
Matrix4f perspective( Matrix4f::perspective( 60.0f, ( size.width / size.height ), 0.5f, 1500.f ) );
Matrix4f lookAt( Matrix4f::lookAt( size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 2.0f, size.height / 1.1566f, size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) );
Matrix4f m( ( perspective * lookAt ).translate( -( size.width / 2.0f ), -( size.height / 2.0f ), -( size.height/ 1.1566f ) ) );
glLoadMatrixf( m.get() );
```

This works for 640x960 resolution, but does not work for any other like 1024x768. In other resolutions it does not exactly map to the screen pixels.

I want to set up perspective projection because I want to provide an ability to rotate the sprites along x and y axes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was with the multiplication order. The above code now works fine with any resolution.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to set up perspective projection in OpenGL such that it maps exactly to the screen pixels

By its very nature this kind of mapping will hold for only one certain depth. For all others it simply can't map view X,Y to viewport X,Y

> I want to set up perspective projection because **I want to provide an ability to rotate the sprites along x and y axes too.**

Nothing stops you from doing that with an ortho projection.

Comment: Yes, I want to use only one depth value, 0.0f for instance, for all the objects. In an ortho projection, the rotation does not look real along x or y axes. All it does it changes the width/height.

Comment: @user2206696: Well in that case a perspective makes sense. However you should use directly build a frustum instead of having a perspective function do it for you. Also lookAt is total overkill, a simple translate(0,0,-near) suffices. Also the projection (frustum or ortho) belongs into the projection matrix, not modelview.

Comment: Thanks but could you please let me know how to set the projection so that it maps the screen pixels?

Comment: @user2206696: One cannot "set the projection so that it maps the screen pixels" in the perspectivic case. What one could do is "mapping the screen pixels" (analogous to how an orthogonal projection is often used to get "pixel coordinates") at a certain depth plane. Is that what you want?

Comment: Ok, let's say I have created a window of 1024x768. I want to set up a perspective projection so that when I position a sprite at (0, 0, 0) it should render from the lower left corner of the window. Then let's say I create another window of size 800x600, recalculate my projection for that window, and when I render a sprite at (400, 300, 0) it should render from the center of the window.